# How to store values after reading a word in a file in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

I am trying to read a file in C and then store values after a certain word is read. For example, in my input.txt file, the following are the contents:

```
GREETINGS
Hello 13
Namaste 24
Hola 36
FLAVORS
Vanilla 23
Chocolate 78
```

I want to read past `GREETINGS` and then store `Hello` and its value `13` then `Namaste` and its value `24`, etc. And then read past `FLAVORS` and store `Vanilla` and its value `23`, etc. And so on...

I know how to open a file but not sure how to proceed from there.

```
void readInput() {

    char input_file[100];

    FILE *fp;

    printf("Please enter the name of the file you would like to read: \n");
    scanf("%s", input_file);
    printf("You entered: %s\n", input_file);

    fp = fopen(input_file, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist.\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("This file exists!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample data it is not clear whether the lines with data have the always the same format. So I
suggest that you store in a variable the current mode (that means `GREETINGS`, `FLAVOR`, etc) and you call
a specific parsing function for every mode depending of the value of the current
mode.

I'd create this enum first

```
typedef enum {
    MODE_GREETINGS = 0,  // <-- important that this value is 0
    MODE_FLAVORS,
    ...
    MODE_INVALID
} Modes;
```

and a variable (this can be a global variable) with all modes:

```
const char *modes_lookup[] = {
    "GREETINGS",
    "FLAVORS",
    ...
};
```

Then I'd write a function that returns the mode:

```
Modes get_mode(const char *src)
{
    if(src == NULL)
        return MODE_INVALID;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof modes_lookup / sizeof modes_lookup[0]; ++i)
    {
        if(strcmp(src, modes_lookup[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    }

    return MODE_INVALID;
}
```

Now you can parse the file like this:

```
char line[1024];

Modes mode = MODE_INVALID;

size_t lineno = 0;
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
{
    lineno++;
    // removing newline
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;

    Modes newmode = get_mode(line);

    // check if line is a GREETINGS, FLAVOR, etc line
    if(newmode != MODE_INVALID)
    {
        // sets the new mode and continue with the next line
        mode = newmode;
        continue;
    }

    // parsing depending on the current mode

    if(mode == MODE_GREETINGS)
    {
        if(parse_greetings(line) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot parse data on line %zu\n", lineno);
            break;
        }

        continue;
    } 

    if(mode == MODE_FLAVORS) {
        if(parse_flavor(line) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot parse data on line %zu\n", lineno);
            break;
        }

        continue;
    }

    // more (if mode == MODE_xxx) cases as needed

    if(mode == MODE_INVALID)
    {
        // mode == MODE_INVALID
        fprintf(stderr, "File does not start with a mode line.\n");
        break;
    }

}
```

Then you've got to write the `parse_greetings`, `parse_flavor`, `parse_xxx` functions. Like I said
before, it's not clear from your sample whether the format will be always the
same, so it depends on the format whether you use `strtok` or `sscanf`. Also
your description of how and where you want to store the values is very vague, so
I don't know what would be the best for your.
The easiest would be `sscanf` and if the data line gets more complex, you can then
use `strtok`.

For example with `sscanf`

```
int parse_greetings(const char *line)
{
    if(line == NULL)
        return 0;

    char name[20];
    int val;

    if(sscanf(line, "%19s %d", name, val) != 2)
        return 0;


    // do whatever you need with 'name' and 'val'

    return 1;
}
```

And with `strtok`:

```
int parse_greetings(char *line)
{
    if(line == NULL)
        return 0;

    char name[20];
    int val;

    const char *delim = " \t\r\n";

    char *token = strtok(line, NULL);

    // line has only delimiters
    if(token == NULL)
        return 0;

    strncpy(name, token, sizeof name / sizeof name[0]);
    name[(sizeof name / sizeof name[0]) - 1] = 0;

    token = strtok(NULL, delim);

    if(token == NULL)
        return 0;

    char *end;

    val = strtol(token, &end, 0);

    // check if token is a number
    if(*end != '\0')
        return 0;

    // do whatever you need with 'name' and 'val'

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exact criteria you're using to choose which lines to skip, but the next step for reading lines is to use `fscanf` or `fgets`. [This tutorial should help you get started with reading files in C.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm)

Edit, to make this more relevant after your comment:

`fgets` may be a better choice. You'll need to read each line, then loop through each character, to check if they are all uppercase.
If they are not uppercase, you can use `fscanf`, using the format `%s %d`, to scan the data line.

Comment: If the word is in all caps, then I have to skip it and read the contents until it until the next word in all caps

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it slightly more relevant to your use case.